# Can't resolve name to IP using private BIND DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, network-adapter, hostname, bind

I am setting up experiment virtual network using virtualbox. I configured a BIND DNS server and have some hosts all using ubuntu linux.

I made sure that the forward and reverse configuration files are syntactically correct using:

```
sudo named-checkzone xyz1.com forward.xyz1.com
```

resulted in:

```
zone xyz1.com/IN: loaded serial 5
OK
```

and:

```
sudo named-checkzone 56.168.192.in-addr.arpa reverse.xyz1.com
```

resulted in:

```
zone 56.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 3
OK
```

I have the following `forward.xyz1.com` file:

```
$TTL    604800

@       IN      SOA     dns1.xyz1.com. admin.xyz1.com. (
                              6         ; Serial
                         604820         ; Refresh
                          86600         ; Retry
                        2419600         ; Expire
                         604600 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers - NS records
    IN  NS  dns1.xyz1.com.
    IN  NS  dns2.xyz1.com.

; name servers - A records
dns1.xyz1.com.          IN      A       192.168.56.3
dns2.xyz1.com.          IN      A       192.168.56.5

; 192.168.56.0/24 - A records
host1.xyz1.com.         IN      A       192.168.56.7
host2.xyz1.com.         IN      A       192.168.56.8
```

I have a virtual machine (host1) with this IP: `192.168.56.7`

I have my own Windows machine (actual non virtual). I made sure that I can ping the DNS server that has this IP: `192.168.56.3` and host1 machine that has this IP: `192.168.56.7`

I changed my Windows machine network card to use the private DNS server as follows:

[image]

I want to test that the private DNS can resolve host names. So I typed in the browser the following host: `host1.xyz1.com`
I got an error and the browser could not resolve the name. Note that when I put the IP of the host `192.168.56.7` in the browser, I get the page. I am also able to ping it as I said earlier.

There is something wrong in the DNS but I am new to setting up DNS server. Can you point to me what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here is the `named.conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "xyz1.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/forward.xyz1.com";
};

zone "56.168.192.in-addr.arpa"{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/reverse.xyz1.com";
};
```

Here is the `named.conf.options`:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on port 53 { localhost; 192.168.56.0/24; };
    recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
    allow-query { localhost; 192.168.56.0/24; };
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };

};
```

The server and host both running and I can ping them from my Windows machine:
pinging the dns server:

```
Pinging 192.168.56.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

and pinging the host:

```
Pinging 192.168.56.7 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.56.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

However, my network is virtual. Meaning that I am configuring DHCP in the virtualbox Network Host Manager as follows:
[image]

My actual machine (the Window machine) network configurations is:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : my-wireless-network
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxx
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.xx.xxx.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.xx.xxx.xxx

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4844:71a7:73f1:69d2%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: Assuming that 192.168.56.3 is the `named` server, how exactly did you configure it – what does the `zone{}` block look like?

Comment: Is named actually running - you've checked the config files, but you've not confirmed you actually started the server?
Also, try doing a dns lookup using `nslookup` in a command prompt on windows. It'll give you more infomation - you may need to forward the ports to allow the DNS to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration was correct. The solution was just to make sure that when you set the DNS IP in the network interface card to choose the right network card.

In my case it was a bit tricky because I am working in virtual network and I had to set the DNS IP in the virtual interface not the actual wireless card.